# I want to write a get and set method using the arrow function

Tags: typescript

I am using `typescript 3.1.6` .

Can I write a get and a set method using an arrow function:

```js
export class foo {
/* attributures ... */ 
/* constructor ... */ 

/* ---- Example ---- */

get bar = ():string => this.anAttributeToGet;
set baz = (attr: string) => this.anAttributeToSet = attr;

/* ---- ( obviously does not run ) ---- */
}
```

instead of a function statement?

```js
export class foo {
/* attributures ... */ 
/* constructor ... */ 

/* ---- Example ---- */

get bar():string{return this.anAttributeToGet;}
set baz(attr: string){this.anAttributeToSet = attr;}

/* ---- Example ---- */
}
```

Comment: Yes you can use arrow functions that is totally valid

Comment: It is without a `get` and a `set`. With `get` and `set` it does not run.

Comment: And what advantage will you get out of it?

Comment: Remember that if you use arrow function, the `this` in the getter/setter does not refer to the class itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, you cannot use arrow syntax for class getters/setters, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so. Just wanted to be sure.